# Prevent duplicate results from a form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a list of names in a text file `texttyy.txt` that is echoed onto the html with **PHP**:

```
<?php
$myFile = "texttyy.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
?>
```

`texttyy.txt`:

```
<li>Artist 1
<li>Artist 2
<li>Artist 3
<li>Artist 4
...
```

This list(`texttyy.txt`) is updated through a form:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Artist: <input type="text" name="Artist">

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I am looking for a way to prevent duplicates in the form. With Jquery and php.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$search =  $_POST["Artist"];
?>
```

**JQuery - (attempt): **

```
if( $('li:contains("<?php echo $search; ?>")')){
return false; /* Don't submit the form*/
alert("Already artist");

}else{
return /*submit the form*/
}
```

I can't see why this doesn't work!!

Comment: Or a database/table with a `UNIQUE` index. Flat files will only get you so far...

Answer (score 1):

If you have to store the list in a flat file, don't store it with markup attached. When outputting the file, loop over it and output it with the markup you require. An example is as follows:

Instead of your:

```
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
```

Do:

```
while ($theData = fgets($fh)) {
    echo "<li data-val='{$theData}'>{$theData}</li>";
}

fclose($fh);
```

This is also better for memory usage.

You now have a list which can be worked with in jQuery something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
   name_val = $(this).find('input[name=Artist]');

   if ($('li[data-val="'+name_val+'"]').length) {
      return false;
      alert('Oh noes');
   }
});
```

Once the jQuery has passed through, you're right to re-check in PHP. Something like this (after the obvious fopen of the file)...

```
while ($theData = fgets($fh)) {
    if ($theData == $_POST["Artist"]) {
        die('Oh noes');
    }
}
```

All untested for syntax et al. but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Like this? $f = fopen("texttyy.txt", "r");
while ($theData = fgets($fh)) {
    if ($theData == $_POST["Artist"]) {
        die('Already entered');
    }
}
fclose($f);

Comment: I am getting this `Warning: fgets(): 2 is not a valid stream resource`

Comment: Your example assigns the fopen() to $f but does the get on $fh. That may be your problem.

Comment: $fh = fopen("texttyy.txt", "r"); while ($theData = fgets($fh)) { if ($theData == $_POST["Artist"]) { die('Already entered'); } } fclose($fh);

Comment: Something in that region, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
echo implode("\n",array_unique(explode("\n",$theData)));
```

instead of the original `echo`?

Comment: Hmm. Can you try to change the echo to print_r and run the page incrementaly by removing the function calls one by one, and show the result?

Comment: Sorry I am new to PHP. How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<ul id="list">
<li>Artist 1</li>
<li>Artist 2</li>
<li>Artist 3</li>
<li>Artist 4</li>
</ul>

  <?php
       $search = "Artist 1";
  ?>

 <script>
$('form').submit(functon(){
    if($('#list li:contains("<?php echo $search; ?>")')){
      alert('Already Artist');
    return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work it doesn't terminate the form from submitting

Comment: Just updated the code with "return false" statement. Try now.